# If A1 = A2, and B1>B2 then hide Row 2. What formulas/rules to use and where?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel I have a problem...I don't know many formulas/rules.

This is my case:

Scenario 1)

```
     A       B      C
1.| Drw....3350......03
2.| Drw....3350......02
```

This is my desire:

I want to hide row 2.

---

Scenario 2)

```
     A       B       C
1.| Drw....3350........03
2.| Img.....3350........02
```

This is my desire:

I want to keep both rows.

---

My problem in words:

Scenario 1: Because A1 & A2 + B1 & B2 are the same, I want to hide the row with the smallest number in column C.

Scenario 2: Because A1 & A2 are different I want to keep both rows, even though B1 & B2 are the same.

This is a simplified example. Column A could consist of hundreds of rows with mixed values. However, Column A is text and column B and C are values.

There will not be such a case when C1 & C2 are the same. (only if someone typed in wrong)

---

What I am asking:

I don't know what formulas or rules to use in Excel and would prefer to not use VBA for this. Seems like such a simple task but I just don't know how to.

Anyone?

Comment: This is pretty complex without VBA. What about a scenario where row 1 matches row 10 exactly? Should one of those rows be hidden?

Comment: You won't be able to use formulas to hide rows, you would have to use VBA for that. You *could* use conditional formatting to make the rows *appear* empty, but that comes with the risk of people accidentally overwriting data that they can't immediately see. Also, conditional formatting when used in bulk will impact calculation turnaround time, so it's better used sparingly.

Comment: If you want formulas, no VBA, an alternative is to use a new worksheet to store matching values.  Thus, any non-matching (otherwise hidden) rows will just not show up.  That way you don't need VBA and can still "hide" rows.  Would that work?

Comment: A non VBA solution would be to use conditional formatting to make the undesired items be white in color.

Answer (score 0):

In your Title you mention `and B1>B2` and then give two examples in both of which the 'B' values are the same, so assuming you mean to hide the lower `C` value where the `A` values match and the `B` values match then in a helper column, say `E`:

```
=A2&B2
```

and in another column (I chose `H`):

```
=AND(MIN(IF(E7=E:E,C:C))=C7,MAX(IF(E7=E:E,C:C))<>C7)
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and copied down to suit. Then filter that column to select for `FALSE`:

[image]